# Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 cannot open browse file

Tags: visual-studio-2010

Please help me fix this problem. My Visual Studio doesn't respond when i click "Open File" or "Browse" or "Add reference". it should be show the open file dialog, but no error message just nothing happen. how to fix it?

Comment: I got same problem. help me if any body found a sulotion